# Conditional in Kendo grid column template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to apply a condition in my kendo grid column template.

Here is my code:

```
columns: [
{
    field: "EmpName",
    title: "Name",
    template: '<a href="\\#" onclick="showName();">#= if (empName == null){ "show xxx"
               } else {
                   // I want to show actual name if it is not null
                   empName
               } #</a>'
},
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check this

```
'<a href="" onclick="showName();">'# if( empName==null) {#<span>show xxx<span># } else {#<span>#: empName#<span>#} #'</a>'
```

Comment: <span> tag can be removed if required - {##: empName##}

Answer (score 6):

something like this should work for you:

```
# if(test == null) { #
    <span style="border:1px solid red"></span>
# } else { #
    <span style="border:1px solid lime"></span>
# } #
```

Don´t know how to do inline at the moment.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me! I wanted to show a `link` if my field was `null` else N/A. This worked like charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hope it will also help

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div id="details-container">
       <dt> Name:</dt> #= Name #
      <br>  
       <dt>Selected Device: </dt>  iOS:-# if (PushToiOS == true) { #Yes# } else { #No# } #,
                                   Android:-# if (PushToAndroid == true) { #Yes# } else { #No# } #,
                                   WP:-# if (PushToWP == true) { #Yes# } else { #No# } #
      <br>
       <dt>Expire Date:</dt> #= kendo.toString(ExpiredDate, "MM/dd/yyyy") #
      <br>
    </div>
</script>
```