# How do I pass parameters to javascript in a kendo grid column template?

Tags: kendo-ui, parameter-passing, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with a column template. I try to pass a value from the current row as a parameter for my javascript function. My code:

```
{
  field: "CrmTaskId",
  title: "Crm ", 
  template: '<a href="javascript:hrefTest(#=CrmTaskId#);" ># if( CrmTaskId==null) {#<span><span># } else {#<span>#: CrmTaskId#<span>#} #</a>'

}
```

`hrefTest` is javascript function with one param. But it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: hrefTest(CrmTaskId) or hrefTest(data.CrmTaskId) not working

Comment: Have a look a this [post][1]......


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740487/conding-in-kendo-grid-column-template/18755973#18755973

Answer (score 3):

It can be done like this

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript: void(0);' 
 onclick=\"return YourJSFunction('#= OpportunityUrl #');\">#= OpportunityName #</a>")
```

This is part of the column definition, so what it is saying is...Make the OpportunityName
clickable and pass in the OpportunityUrl. `#= Field #` is the syntax for pulling values off of the Model.

Comment: I don't use mvc helpers. Only html and javascript. How to define client template in javascript?

Comment: Did you try placing what is inside `ClientTemplate()` to `template:`

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819127/how-to-call-javascript-method-from-clienttemplate-in-kendo-grid

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with your code but not able to reproduce this issue. Please create new HTML/CSHTML page and check it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
var movies = [
                    { "CrmTaskId": 1, "rating": 9.2, "year": 1994, "title": "The Shawshank Redemption"},
                    { "CrmTaskId": 2, "rating": 9.2, "year": 1972, "title": "The Godfather"},
                    { "CrmTaskId": null, "rating": 9, "year": 1974, "title": "The Godfather: Part II" },
                    { "CrmTaskId": '', "rating": 9.9, "year": 1874, "title": "The Godmother: Part III" }

                ];

function hrefTest(CrmTaskId)
{
    alert("CrmTaskId is: " + CrmTaskId);
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: movies,
            pageSize: 10
        },
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "CrmTaskId",
            title: "Crm"
        }, {
            field: "title",
            title: "title"
        },
    {
        template: '<a href="javascript:hrefTest(#=CrmTaskId#);" ># if( CrmTaskId==null) {#<span><span># } else {#<span>#: CrmTaskId#<span>#} #</a>'
    }
    ]
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try with the below code snippet.

Comment: Your code is working. This kendo grid issue. You cannot use value from the same colum as template.

Comment: You can not add Field and Template both in one column. Because they are same as BoundColumn and TemplateColumn. If needed then please use ClientTemplate for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
{
   field: "Field",
   editable: true,
   title: "Title",
   template: showRelatedLink,
   allownull: true,
   width: 100
}
```

and then in your function :

```
function showRelatedLink(container, options)
{
    var yourVariable = container.YourField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a field to a function like this too:

Grid:

```
    columns: [
       { field: "ProductTypeID", title: "Type", template: "#=product_type_to_name(ProductTypeID)#" },
    ]
```

Function:

```
function product_type_to_name(product_type_id) {
    console.log(product_type_id);
    var name = "";
    // convert ID to name
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this 
    `{
  field: "DisplayChangedFrom",
  title: "From",
  template:"#=generateTemplate(DisplayChangedFrom)#

            },`

Then the function
    `function generateTemplate(items) {
        var html = "<ul>";
        if (items !== null && items.length > 0) {
            for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
                html += "<li>";
                html += items[x];
                html += "</li>";
            }
        }
        html += "</ul>";
        return html;
    };`

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please edit your answer and provide an explanation to your code.